# Multi-website language switcher not showing

Tags: multistore, url, index

This is my first time creating a multi-lingual webshop, so first I created 2 storeviews, where the switcher was working fine. Then I found out that I needed to create multi-websites instead.
I did it in the same process, but it is not working now. 
I've added a few screenshots so you can see what I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store switcher does not appear unless you have 2 store views under the current website you are viewing.
Since you have only one store view for each website this does not appear.

You can try to change the `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/switch/languages.phtml` to support all store views like this (untested code):

```
<?php $stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('neq'=>0));?>
<?php if(count($stores)>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Your Language:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($stores as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The problem appears because on `da.thirstforgreat....` it still runs the `thirstforgreat....` website. I think the problem appears because you have the line `$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']: '';` just like @roman204 said in the other answer. Remove that.

Comment: Hmm I tried deleting that now, but there still seems to be somm kind of issue. Eventhough I changed language and so on for the danish website, it hasn't changed on da.thirstforgreat...

Comment: I think this a different problem then. It is not in the scope of this question. This was about showing the store switcher. I think you should ask an other question.

Answer (score 0):

your website selection will not work, you override the `$mageRunCode` in line 95.
it should be

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']{
    case 'domain.com':
       $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = 'run_code';
    break;
    ...
    ...
   }
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']: '';
```

but to get the switcher showing you should add 2 or more storeviews at a website.