# Magento 1.9 multi website with language switcher enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency, store-switcher

I have a multilanguage and multicurrency installation: test.com and test.com/en

1. `test.com` has **Italian** language and **euro** currency
2. `test.com/en` has **english** language and **dollars** currency

I needed to create 2 websites instead of 2 stores because each language needs to have separate currency (200 euro by default are converted by magento but I want to be able to set 200 dollars without that magento converts nothing) so I enabled "

> system -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog- > price -> Catalog
>   price scope

to **website** and now each product translation has different currencies and everything is fine

The problem is that now I only have 1 store on each website so the language switcher, the currency switcher and the alternate links does not work

I was able to convert the language switcher with [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31289/multi-website-language-switcher-not-showing#answer-31291) but for the others I can't find anything and I don't think it's the right way